# Set permissions to files after MSIX publishing

Tags: wpf, .net-core, msix

I have .Net Core WPF application and would like to distribute it from my web site.
I'd created the folder `app` in `wwwroot` and published MSIX into it.
Then I created page on my website and put the link to appropriate `appbundle` file there.
But when I'd tried to download this app I got a 403 error. I found out that such error arise because of insufficient permission set of `msixbundle` file. The folder, contained this file had limited set of permissions and has not inherited proper permissions from the parent directory.
I believe that when I publish the project, VS moves files from some temp directory there instead of copying them.

Could you suggest how should I publish the project properly? Is it possible to setup some "after publishing" event in order to set the proper permissions to published files?

I wouldn't like to setup the full-fledged devops process just now, because it is very beginning stage of the project.

Comment: Did you really [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/msix-core/msixcore-clickonce-solution) your web server to serve MSIX packages?

Comment: @mm8, No, but it's not an option in my case, I believe. That example describes how to publish existing package. If I decide to follow this way, I should 1) publish the package, 2) find the msixbundle, 3) include or copy it into the site project, because the published package located in different folder every time. 4) publish the site project. It is even more complicated than in my case just publish the package and change the permissions manually.